# docker function does not call itself recursively when using sudo?

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, bash-functions

I am on an Ubuntu EC2 instance on AWS, and I have this in my ~/.bashrc file:

```
docker(){
   sudo docker "$@"
}

export -f docker;
```

since I trust docker, I basically run all my docker commands with sudo and this like the best thing I ever did for my devops experience on a remote server. however, I have no idea why it works - I would think the docker function would call itself recursively until some stack exploded or something. My guess is that sudo will only call commands not bash functions?

I tried doing this for example:

```
docker(){
   sudo command docker "$@"
}

export -f docker;
```

but when I called `docker ps` I got this:

> sudo: command: command not found

anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Why don’t you add your user to docker group, so you do not need sudo!?

Comment: because I don't want my user to do everything as root? how does that work?

Comment: You can read more here: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` checks the `PATH` (usually a "`secure_path`" and not even your users nor root's full `PATH`) for **commands** and therefore does not work with builtins and functions.  `command` is a builtin and sudo is using the `docker` command in your `PATH` rather than your function.

You *could* resolve this by creating a wrapper script that points to the `command` builtin (or similarly with your docker function) and putting that script in the `PATH`, but you **should not** do that.  You should just run docker itself with `sudo` when needed.

Comment: umm what's actually wrong with the sudo thing I have now? I suppose because a malicious user could overwrite what docker points to the sudo secure PATH?

Comment: Using `sudo` in a script or function is similar to logging in only as root.  If you are going to permanently override security privileges, what is the point of even having them in the first place?

Comment: I guess you 1. assume it's only trusted people on the server. 2. given the previous, nobody f*cks with what docker points to. 3. assume you trust what docker points to. Then always `sudo docker` is ok? idk

Comment: @AlexanderMills i know where youre coming from, but if your security practices are based on an *idk* then that should be a red flag

Comment: not based on idk, i mean if someone breaks into our server, we are f'kd anyway...it's merely about whether you trust an installed utility or not